# Long running index rebuild

Tags: sql-server, index, ola-hallengren

I'm running an index rebuild using Ola Hallengren's script below.

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
 @Databases = 'insight',
 @FragmentationLow = NULL,
 @FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
 @FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
 @FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
 @FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
 @LogToTable = 'Y'
```

It has been running for almost 2 days. How bad would it be to kill the job? The index it is running against is 78% fragmented. The table at issue has 111,543,114 rows.

Comment: If the command that's running is a reorg, you can just kill it. If it's a rebuild, it'll have to roll back, which is single threaded, and may take a very long time. This might be a good time to [stop blindly rebuilding indexes](https://groupby.org/conference-session-abstracts/why-defragmenting-your-indexes-isnt-helping/).

Comment: Maybe I should have added a time out in the T-SQL so it doesn't run for ever. The real question is kill or not as it is doing a rebuild and not a reorg.

Comment: Is it an online rebuild or offline of this index?. How large is that index? It's not a huge amount of rows, wondering at the size. Any messages in your error log look related?

Comment: It is an offline rebuild. There are 4 indexes on the table for a total of 24 GB. No errors in the log. The table is 63 GB.

Comment: How big is the index it's working on? Are you sure it's not blocked and has been working on the individual index for that long? Tony's suggestion to look at sp_whoisactive will help clear that up. Even if your storage is REALLY slow, I would expect to see messages in the log about the storage not responding at that runtime.

Comment: No blocking is going on.  sp_whoisactive doesn't show my sql job for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see if it's doing a reorg or a rebuild by using [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) or something similar and inspecting the sql_text column.

If you kill it, you will not lose the work it has done on previous indexes that were defragmented as part of this script.  Those are done and committed.

As for the current index it's defragmenting, if it's doing a reorg, the progress it has made will not be lost if you kill it.  If it's a rebuild, which seems to be the case given the data you've provided, it's still OK to kill it, but you will lose any progress that has been made.

Comment: Ran sp_whoisactive and I don't see my job as running. So if I kill the TSQL running, will there still be an index on the table?

Comment: It should show it, so I'm not sure what's going on.  Index rebuild creates an entirely new index, and when it is done, it drops the old index and renames the new index.  So if you kill it, it will roll back all of the work it did to create the new index.  It should not affect the old index.  If the index is somehow lost, you are one very unlucky person as that would be quite a significant defect.

Comment: No blocking is going on. How do I check to see if a new index is being created?

Comment: Are you running an agent job, or running the query in an SSMS window from your machine? Regardless, sp_WhoIsActive WILL show an active index reorg/rebuild. Have you checked dbo.CommandLog (wherever you created that)? That will show the start and end time for the processing of the indexes on the table in question.

Comment: Running the query from SSMS on my machine. sp_whoisactive doesn't show an active index reorg/rebuild going on. I've looked at the CommandLog and it shows: the index job ran. No new records have been added to the CommandLog since Noon on 6 April. No idea what is going on. Arg!

Comment: Are you sure the query window where you're running sp_whoisactive is connected to the server where you think this is running?  If there is a reindex running, it will show up.

Comment: Yes, the query window is pointing to the correct server. sp_whoisactive only shows 4 items and none show an index rebuild

Comment: Could you check the session_id in the SSMS window that is executing IndexOptimize.

Can you see that session_id when you execute sp_WhoIsActive? What is it showing?

Comment: I checked the session_id in SSMS and ran sp_WhoIsActive. The session_id is not listed. Still executing after 2 days and 16 hours.

Comment: What if you do selects from sys.dm_exec_sessions, and sys.dm_exec_requests, with a filter on your session_id? DBCC INPUTBUFFER could also be interesting.

Comment: Ran query against sys.dm_exec_sessions, shows query sleeping, last request time: 6 Apr at 1206 PM. sys.dm_exec_requests shows nothing. Will doing the dbcc during prod hours cause any slowness?

Comment: By default, don't run reindexing during production hours as it will likely impact users.  A lot of things to consider when deciding to break this rule--too much to write here.

Comment: Yea, started in non prod hours but it keeps going. Doesn't seem to be doing anything tho. Emailing with Ola at the present.

Comment: After emailing with Ola, on his suggestion, I did this: I closed SSMS, SSMS asked if I wanted to stop the job, I said yes, then SSMS closed. For an extra measure I went ahead and restarted my computer. Everything looks good now. I was using SSMS 17.5. Just upgraded SSMS to 17.6. Could have been a bug in SSMS 17.5.

Comment: The strange thing was that in SSMS it looked like the stored procedure was executing, but there was no request in SQL Server (no entry in sys.dm_exec_requests for this session_id). I am thinking about if it could have been some bug in SSMS?